# Override of Button component doesn't change the hover color

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change the color of the all the Button's in the project by overriding the theme css. The color of the button has changed but hover color is still transparent, how can I override it ?

Is there any other way to this apart from adding a class to each of my buttons.

*Also shouldn't all the variants of a button follow the css of the root?*

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: '#35C37D',
      main: '#35C37D',
      dark: '#35C37D',
      // contrastText: will be calculated to contrast with palette.primary.main
    },
    secondary: {
      light: '#35C37D',
      main: '#35C37D',
      // dark: will be calculated from palette.secondary.main,
      contrastText: '#35C37D',
    },
    // error: will use the default color
  },
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      // Name of the rule
      root: {
        // Some CSS
        background: 'rgba(53, 195, 125, 100)',
        borderRadius: 0,
        border: 0,
        colorInherit: '#fff',
        color: 'white',
        height: 40,
        padding: '0 30px',
        boxShadow: '4px 9px 26px 0 rgba(16,124,71,0.10)',
        '&:hover': {
          textDecoration: 'none',
          backgroundColor: '#35C37D',
          // Reset on touch devices, it doesn't add specificity
          '@media (hover: none)': {
            backgroundColor: '#35C37D',
          },
        },
      },
      textPrimary: {
        color: '#fff',
      },
      textSecondary: {
        color: '#fff',
      },
      contained: {
        color: '#fff',
      },

      containedPrimary: {
        color: '#fff',
      },

      containedSecondary: {
        color: '#fff',
      },

      raised: {
        color: '#fff',
      },

      colorInherit: {
        color: '#fff',
      },

    },
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily: 'azo-sans-web',
    // The default font size of the Material Specification.
    fontSize: 14, // px
    fontWeightLight: 300,
    fontWeightRegular: 400,
    fontWeightMedium: 500,
    // Tell Material-UI what's the font-size on the html element.
    // 16px is the default font-size used by browsers.
    htmlFontSize: 16,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figured it out.
Here is the code sandbox if anyone cares https://codesandbox.io/s/y2qyk9rn4x

Just need to add this for each variant:

```
outlined: {
  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: "#35C37D"
  }
},
```